# SQL Finding all related entries

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2008, many-to-many, data-modeling

Having a table of users, any user can create a friendship with another user. So,

```
UserTable
-----------
User1
User2
User3


FriendshipTable
-----------
User1, User3
User2, User5
User3, User5
User5, User9
```

Part 1: I'm looking for a way to get the full set of friends, friends of friends, etc. For example User1 would return: User1, User5, User2, User9

Part 2: It would be useful but not necessary if I could get the size of the largest network of people

Alternately, is there's a better way of storing the connection between users that would make pulling the information I need easier? Like maybe building and merging a list of friendship groups as the friendships are created?

I've found some similar posts on here, but none of them seem to follow the network past the first level of depth.

I imagine there's solutions out there, but I don't even know what to search on.

Comment: MSSQL 2008 and .NET The solution doesn't have to be only SQL, I'm thinking I'd need some temp tables and recursion.

Comment: If it's SQL 2K8 you can use recursive CTEs and specify the `MAXRECUSION` option, either at `0` (unlimited) or some known limit. FoF can very rapidly expand and will contain cycles in the relationship graph.

Comment: I was thinking CTEs too. The examples I've found of recursion with CTEs so far all use a parent/child hierarchical relationship between records in the same table. I haven't come across one yet that demonstrated using a second relationship table like I would probably need.

Answer (score 0):

CTE is the way to go here (but you need to be careful with MAXRECURSION if you want to get a large number of degrees of separation between friends). In your situation the UserTable is actually irrelevant. All you care about is the relationship table (FriendshipTable).

```
CREATE TABLE #UserFriendship (User1 VARCHAR(20), User2 VARCHAR(20))

INSERT #UserFriendship VALUES ('A', 'B')
INSERT #UserFriendship VALUES ('B', 'C')


;WITH friends AS
(
    SELECT User1, User2 
    FROM #UserFriendship
    UNION ALL
    SELECT friends.User1, child.User2
    FROM friends
    JOIN #UserFriendship child ON
        friends.User2 = child.User1
)
SELECT * FROM friends
```